# why my analytics and ad-words reports are not matching?

Tags: google-analytics

I have register with analytics and adwords accounts for my business. I have linked my adwords account to my analytics account. I have only one analytics and one adwords account. But the problem is, results for both analytics and adwords are showing differently in terms of goal completions.

Example 1 : 7 Conversions are showing in adwords report and 5 conversions are showing in analytics.

Example 2 : 7 Conversions are showing in adwords report and 9 conversions are showing in analytics.

Example 3 : 7 Conversions are showing in adwords report and 7 conversions are showing in analytics.

Note : some times it is showing equal and some time it is showing different.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because GA attributes conversions to the time of the transaction/completed goal and Adwords to the time the advert was clicked (at least that is how it's used to be). I am not sure this is on-topic, though, since it is not about "specific programming problems"

Comment: @EikePierstorff do you think only the time difference is the main problem ?